# Custom animation during pull to refresh

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to customize an Pull To Refresh view. I'm wondering how to make something similar to below animation?

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/188232/screenshots/1956070/open-uri20150303-11-rtr4op))</sub>

Comment: Anything you have tried? Any research? Maybe you could visit cocoacontrols.com?

Comment: Of course i've researched a lot on these sites, but haven't found anything. So if you really believe there is something on these sites, then be my guest

Comment: I'm in a hurry, but I'll your guest later, let me get to my mac.

Comment: http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Subin mentioned, I would take a look at this tutorial (http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/) (You may have to update it to Swift2 code). It helped me with making custom 'Pull to Refresh' animations. Afterwards check out this software (http://www.coreanimator.com/) Core Animator allows you to create awesome animations and it generates the corresponding Swift code for you. 
I've made a few custom 'Pull to Refresh' animation with this software and if you have a great imagination then the possibilities are limitless. If you're interested they have a few tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwhWhmJ8J1Y) and if you want examples with the code I'll post a few on my github account. I hope this helps!